# Control robot using controller/followjointtrejectory/goal

Tags: ros, follow-joint-trajectory, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
Is it possible to control a robot by using the topic `controller/followjointTrejectory/goal`. I could see when using moveit, move_group is publishing joint goals to this topic. Similarly, can I control the robot without moveit. I tried publishing joint goal to goal topic. Rostopic echo also giving the data which I published. But robot is not moving. Is there another service to be called after publishing the joint goal.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/340413/control-robot-using-controller/followjointtrejectory/goal/) by [Abhishekpg](https://answers.ros.org/users/50018/abhishekpg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 195 on 2019-12-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) on 2019-12-20**:
Can you please add the console output of the controller node, to find out why the robot is not moving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The topic you are seeing belongs to an action. And yes, you can definitely control the robot this way, without using moveit.

If you look at your current setup, probably you start somewhere the
[joint_trajectory_controller](https://wiki.ros.org/joint_trajectory_controller). You can use it to control your robot directly in the joint space. There is also an rqt plugin for this controller. YOu could use it for a first try.
Or see [here for a Tutorial](https://wiki.ros.org/pr2_controllers/Tutorials/Moving%20the%20arm%20using%20the%20Joint%20Trajectory%20Action) including source code.

Just keep in mind that there is no obstacle avoidance or anything, then. The robot just moves where you ask it to go to.

---

Originally posted by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) with karma: 862 on 2019-12-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0